# Center this with css

Tags: html, css, center

how do i make the center like the links are all off to the left i want them to be center top of the web page... any help?? i have done this before but i dont rember how

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #B0FFF5            
}
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
    float:left; /*supposed to be there */
}
a:link,a:visited
{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#3B5998;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#3B5998;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="fbfame.htm">Fb Fame</a></li>
        <li><a href="donate.htm">Donate</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://Facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Your formatting has floated to the left too...

Comment: @LeeTaylor i know i made that so they display lined up not under eachother.. delete it and run it ull see what i mean

Comment: Well, you're floating each list item to the left then centering an inline element which only expands to be as wide as the text inside it... Why do they need to be floated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the buttons to line up, no matter what the window size is, set a fixed `width` and `margin: 0 auto`:

```
ul
{
    width: 512px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5sxR/1/).

---

Alternatively remove the whitespace between the list items ([or use another technique](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)), set their `display` to `inline-block` and give the container a `text-align: center`:

```
ul
{
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;
}
li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5sxR/2/).

Comment: **Note:** This requires you to manually change the width any time you add/remove items from the menu.

Comment: animuson is right on the first approach. The second does not need a fixed `width`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul
{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;

  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul
{
width:600px;
list-style-type: none;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:0;  
}
```

i remberd how to do it sorry folks